# jQuery real person - un-correct view at IE

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, captcha

I have captcha of jQuery realperson library,  v2.0.1.

At chrome browser it works fix. But at IE, the captcha not looked correctly.

Here is my code (- based on javascipt + html + jQuery +knockout.js):

```
<input type="text" id="captcha" />
<span style="color: red;" data-bind="text: captchaError"></span>
```

js:

```
$('#captcha').realperson();
```

See the pictures - of Chrome and Internet Explorer:

[image]

[image]

---

UPDATE:

after the suggestion to add line-height, I do it but the lettera are not clear:

[image]

Comment: Please add more of your code or create a Jsfiddle or Snippet. Because if you try the snippet below it's work fine in IE and Chrome

Comment: Please try to add the `jquery.realperson.css` after all other css in your page and check it. After if is not resolved, please add a link for i check this issue, Because for me look good in IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have other CSS we force `line-height` of div.

Please try: (Work for me on Chrome and IE 10+)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").realperson();
});
```

```css
.realperson-text{
    line-height:3px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.plugin.js"></script>
<script src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.realperson.js"></script>
<link href="http://keith-wood.name/css/jquery.realperson.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="text" id="test" />
```

Comment: Please try to add the `jquery.realperson.css` after all other css in your page and check it. After if is not resolved, please add a link for i check this issue, Because for me look good in IE

Comment: It doesn't work on my IE 11 browser. Any Different Ideas?

Comment: Ok what's your issue exaclty?

Comment: M having the same issue from the above. I have tried to do as u said and still doesn't work out properly. My IE version is 11.0.9600.16476.